# install boto3 for python2.7 on jetson nano

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to install boto3 for python 2.7 on my jetson nano. It is currently installed in site packages for python3.6 because of which i am able to import it in python3. However i am unable to access it in python2.7. It says module not found.

```
jetson@jetson-desktop:~$ pip install boto3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.17.43)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.43 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3) (1.20.43)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3) (0.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.43->boto3) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.43->boto3) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.43->boto3) (1.15.0)
```

I want it to work for python2. I am not able to direct the installation to python2.

Answer (score 0):

try install with:

- $ git clone https://github.com/boto/boto3.git
- $ cd boto3
- $ virtualenv venv
- $ . venv/bin/activate
- $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
- $ python -m pip install -e .
- $ python -m pip install boto3

and check

https://github.com/boto/boto3